# Hide title of JTable when form is loading?

Tags: java, jtable

I need to hide the JTable from frame, when its loading, and it's visible based on some contition(ex: when click the textfield, then JTable will show).

i tried, but i don't have a luck.

code:

```
jTable1.setvisible(false);
```

(or)

```
jTable1.hide();
```

Comment: Check the JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: It should be `setVisible` <- Java is case sensitive, but you might find something like a `CardLayout` more suitable

Comment: sorry for my mistake, i am using jTable1.setVisible(false); but still table is visible, when running